# Is Stack Overflow the right place to ask technical questions about JIRA configuration?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I've just posted this question on Stack Overflow: [Can I resolve an issue's sub-task using a FishEye smart commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896094/can-i-resolve-an-issues-sub-task-using-a-fisheye-smart-commit)

I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is really the right place however. Stack Overflow definitely has the expertise that I need to get my question answered and has a history of these types of questions, but I'm not a fan of polluting the Stack Overflow database with questions that aren't actually about programming.

Equally, the beta [Project Management Stack Exchange](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) site appears more concerned with project management theory and looks more like a resource for project managers than the people tasked with configuring JIRA in the first place (most likely a sysadmin or a programmer I would have thought).

Thoughts?

Comment: My first instinct would be serverfault.com, actually. Check their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked one of the Stack Overflow moderators if this question would be on-topic on Stack Overflow, and he confirmed that, because it's about software tools used by programmers, the question would be on-topic.

From the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> ## What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> *emphasis is mine*

I'm certain it's off-topic on [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but in the interests of not tossing a question back and forth from site to site, I'm going to leave this on PMSE for a few days or until it either accumulates more community close votes or goes unanswered.

While JIRA questions wouldn't necessarily be off-topic on PMSE, what I believe *would* make this particular question off-topic is the context of the question. You're not asking as a *project manager* using JIRA or someone using JIRA to report information to a project manager, you're asking as a *developer* using JIRA doing developer things that a project manager is likely to have zero involvement in. Project managers typically don't use software version control as their role is more in managing the schedule and resources. The development team typically handles all decisions regarding *how*.

Either way, if you want it moved back to Stack Overflow, just flag it on PMSE and I'll send it back over. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers dude, that fits with what I understood of PMSE's purpose and the split between developer and project manager. I'll follow your lead and leave the question for the mo though :)

Answer (score 8):

Atlassian has a clone setup for customer support type questions at http://answers.atlassian.com

The larger question is whether your FishEye question is "on-topic" for Stack Overflow.  I believe it is on topic.  The FAQ explicitly states on topic questions are questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

So while you probably will got a more "authoritative" answer at their own support site, I believe your question fits within the scope of stackoverflow.com.

Comment: It's a shame that this question was closed anyway just before I was about to post an answer. Urgh! In this case all Jira question not related to Jira API should be closed.

Comment: Hi @Daria - it's open here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/can-i-resolve-an-issues-sub-task-using-a-fisheye-smart-commit.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow seems to be the right place for questions related to Jira. Stack Overflow has appropriate tags and people who continuously monitor them. A lot of similar questions to the one mentioned were answered there.